# Explain the service.js in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm quite new to AngularJS and NodeJS. I'm trying to develop an app using MEAN stack. I just looked through the sample code in the mean.io boilerplate. I created my own app referring the sample app. I'm trying to submit the AngularJS front end and expecting it to call NodeJs server side but it isn't working. I think service.js is messing up something. Here is the service code of sample app. Can any one explain what this code does with respect to Angular client side and NodeJS Server side.

```
'use strict';

//Articles service used for articles REST endpoint
angular.module('mean.articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('articles/:articleId', {
        articleId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: i just updated the question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a new factory in angular called Articles.   The Articles factory has the $resource service injected.  The $resource object is used to setup an object for communicating with a RESTful service, in this case "articles/:articleId" the articleId will be pulled from the _id of the resource objects that are returned from queries using this $resource.  When you call to update on one of the resources it will use the PUT HTTP Verb.

By itself this just defines the factory but doesn't actually make any calls you would need to inject this and use it somewhere like Articles.query();

From the docs

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that
>   parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET
>   operations).

Comment: so does this act as a link between AngularJS and NodeJS api?

Comment: Think of it this way - In your code, you defined a way to call a RESTful service, but you have not yet made use of that service. It's equivalent to you defining a function but not executing it yet...

Comment: as callmekatootie says this is basically the config to create a new service in angular that can later be used but since it's not being used yet it won't be showing any calls by itself.  The next step would be to inject the Articles into another service or a controller and make a call to Articles.query() to get the articles, the objects returned will have methods available to save or delete the object.